Mi fetch no funciona
estoy haciendo un trabajo para la Uni y estamos viendo fetch pero no lo entiendo bien. El tema es que en el live server si me funciona pero en todos los otros metodos para ver la pagina no. Alguna ayuda? Dejo el codigo por si hay algo que corregir
const contenedorCard = document.querySelector("#contenedor-productos");

fetch("./Js/productos.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        productos = data;
        crearCardInicio(productos);
    })

function crearCardInicio (productos){
    productos.forEach(producto => {
        const nuevoProducto = document.createElement("div");
        nuevoProducto.classList = "card-producto";
        nuevoProducto.innerHTML = `
            <img src=${producto.img} alt=${producto.nombre}>
            <h3 class="producto-nombre">${producto.nombre}</h3>
            <p class="producto-precio">$${producto.precio}</p>
            <button class="producto-agregar">Agregar</button>
        `
        contenedorCard.appendChild(nuevoProducto);
        nuevoProducto.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
        .addEventListener("click", () => agregarAlCarrito (producto))
    });
}

Muchas gracias :D

Con otros métodos para ver la página a que te refieres? Probablemente sea porque estás haciendo fetch local, es decir, a archivos que tienes en tu computadora. Los navegadores no permiten que las páginas accedan a los archivos locales, tendrías que subirlo en alguna parte y hacer fetch hacia ahí.
